# regular expression not matching multi line string

Tags: regex, typescript

the example sentence is:

```
"Thanks to this crisis, there has been a wake-up call to some of these neobanks," said Ali Niknam, CEO and founder of Dutch online 
bank Bunq. "To run a healthy business, you need healthy business conduct."
```

and my regex is

```
(said)\s.*,\s(CEO and founder of)\s.*\.
```

I am expecting it to match to

```
said Ali Niknam, CEO and founder of Dutch online 
bank Bunq.
```

but it does not due to the **break** after the word online. is there a way to make it work without modifying the sample text?

Comment: check the edited sentence. SO somehow ate the way it was

Comment: ok try this: `said\s[\s\S]*?,\sCEO and founder of\s[\s\S]*?\.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here: https://regexr.com/5jms2.

1. `.` doesn't include line breaks. You can use `(.|\n)` instead.
2. `*` is greedy by default. Using `*?` makes it non-greedy, i.e. it matches the minimum amount of text until the next expression is matched (in this case- `\.`).

Comment: sorry this is not correct. my problem is different. in my case it is not at all matching anything.

Comment: Then the input text in your post may be incorrect. Please check it.

Comment: see now please.